# При парсинге json c помощью retrofit2 пропустить первый объект

Tags: java, json, android-studio, retrofit2

Работаю с данным json файлом. Мне нужно добраться до 2 объекта, так как в нём содержится нужная мне информация. Но из-за заголовка не могу придумать как это сделать. Помогите, может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Пишу в AndroidStudio на Java

```
[
   {
      "page" : 1,
      "per_page" : "1",
      "total" : 297,
      "pages" : 297
   },
   [
      {
         "longitude" : "-70.0167",
         "adminregion" : {
            "value" : "",
            "iso2code" : "",
            "id" : ""
         },
         "region" : {
            "value" : "Latin America & Caribbean ",
            "iso2code" : "ZJ",
            "id" : "LCN"
         },
         "name" : "Aruba",
         "incomeLevel" : {
            "value" : "High income",
            "iso2code" : "XD",
            "id" : "HIC"
         },
         "lendingType" : {
            "value" : "Not classified",
            "iso2code" : "XX",
            "id" : "LNX"
         },
         "capitalCity" : "Oranjestad",
         "latitude" : "12.5167",
         "id" : "ABW",
         "iso2Code" : "AW"
      }
   ]
]
```

Это класс для парсинга 2 обьекта в json, а для этого мне нужно пропустить заголовок

```
public class CountryNetworkEntity {
        private String id;
        private String iso2code;
        private String capitalCity;
        private String name;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getIso2Code() {
            return iso2code;
        }

        public String getCapitalCity() {
            return capitalCity;
        }
    }
```

Это интерфейс для получения json файла с помощью api

```
public interface BankApi {

    @GET("country")
    Call<List<CountryNetworkEntity>> getCountries(@Query("format") String format, @Query("per_page") int per_page);
}
```

Здесь пытаюсь спарсить ответ. В ошибке получаю

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $[1]

```
Response<List<PageWrapper>> response = bankApi.getCountries("json", 1).execute();
```

Comment: покажите ваш код, что у вас сейчас есть и расскажите что вы пытались сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил с помощью ResponseBody

```
@GET("country")
    Call<ResponseBody> getCountries(@Query("format") String format, @Query("per_page") int per_page);
```

После получения данных, преобразил их в String и удалил лишнее. После парсил уже с помощью Gson

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться обёрткой, что-нибудь типа:

```
public class PageWrapper {
    private long page;
    private long total;
    private List<CountryNetworkEntity> countries;
    ...
    //геттеры, сеттеры
}
```

И в методе api возвращать именно ваш `PageWrapper`, или `List<PageWrapper>` (зависит от того, что вам там приходит в ответе):

```
public interface BankApi {
    @GET("country")
    Call<List<PageWrapper>> getCountries(@Query("format") String format, @Query("per_page") int per_page);
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что заголовок не содержит в себе 2-й json файл, он идёт после него.

Comment: А второй и не нужен, он должен один парситься вот в такой вот формат. Лишнее отбрасываться, а остальное заполняться

Comment: Я уже пробовал данный вариант. Выдает ошибку о том, что ожидается объект, а получаем мы массив

Comment: @Валеркович это говорит о том, что вы пытались массив распарсить в объект. Просто в том месте измените тип на List<>

Comment: Я пробовал, всё равно выдает ошибку, о том что я пытаюсь распарсить в объект.

Comment: Добавьте тогда код с парсингом в вопрос

Comment: Обновил. Надеюсь понятно объяснил в чём проблема